# Trying to connect to PostgreSQL with Entity Framework via Npgsql and C#

Tags: postgresql, c#, entity-framework, npgsql

So, I'm new to databases and only have done a little with PostgreSQL before. I have C# (visual studio 2012) and have downloaded the Entity framework (6). I have also downloaded the latest Npgsql data connection driver and used this tutorial:

[Using Entity Framework 6 with Npgsql 2.1.0](http://fxjr.blogspot.com.br/2014/02/using-entity-framework-6-with-npgsql-210.html?m=1)

Now I have of course installed PostgreSQL and referenced the two dll's in my C# project:

`npgsql.dll` and `npgsql.entityframework.dll`

Now I need to know how to add, view, delete stuff via C# but I can't find any material on using C#, Npgsql and Entity Framework together.

With no material on using Npqsql and Entity Framework 6, I have instead found this tutorial for version 5:

[Create Entity Data Model in Entity Framework 5.0](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/create-dbcontext-in-entity-framework5.aspx)

However, under choose your data connection, when I add a new connection, there is no option to use Npqsql. I really am confused and have been trying to control PostgreSQL via C# for about a week now, I have tried almost every link I can find on Google and am close to giving up. A lot of tutorials show how to drive PostgreSQL directly via Npgsql without using Entity Framework, but I really wanted to use the Entity Framework because I've been told it makes manipulating the database much easier.

Comment: Hi Joseph, I'll try to help you out if I can.  Do you get the Entity Data Model wizard?  What do you get if you choose New Connection?  That's where you will want to configure the postgresql database connection.  

Also, I did see this link that may be very promising:  http://www.wekeroad.com/2014/02/05/using-entity-framework-6-with-postgresql/

Comment: I followed that tutorial and added all the bits into Visual Studio via NuGet, however I do not understand the migration stuff, is that tutorial for migrating an existing project? Also, in the new connection window I am seeing nothing about PostgreSQL, but rather options with regards to Microsoft SQL server.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot?  You may need to open 'options' or 'customize' to register the Postgres driver

Comment: [img1](http://i.imgur.com/LjZGeLi.png) and [img2](http://i.imgur.com/n32YwDJ.png)

Comment: I couldn't find anywhere in the options or customize of visual studio 2012 to register any drivers.

Comment: Surely this is purely a development question and therefore much better asked over on StackOverflow? Probably get a much better response there too and not need a bounty.

Comment: Bounty has been awarded. Time to close this question as off-topic or migrate it to SO. It's purely a developer question, nothing DBA about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend not using Entity Framework with anything else other than SQLSERVER. And then LINQ to SQL may be better. [lightspeed](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/lightspeed) was recommended to me as a better product. I personally have not used it.

Comment: Why? As .NET & Postgresql are both free and open source it seems like something that would be a great choice

Answer (score 1):

you can follow the tutorial in this link in-order to use PostgreSQL under C# and .net framework http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30989/Using-PostgreSQL-in-your-C-NET-application-An-intr

for managing the database side you can use `aquafold` (in my opinion one of the best database management for PostgreSQL check the following link http://www.aquafold.com/), `PGAdmin` http://www.pgadmin.org/ or EMS http://www.sqlmanager.net/ . those database management program will help you a lot if you want to make the management of the database using GUI (easier to use than terminal screen)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue using a non-free ORM
http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/articles/tutorial_ef.html

Comment: Please add the important points to your answer to prevent link rot.

Answer (score 0):

U have to use command line if you want to do it in database first approach and if you want to do as code first then make sure you install all the necessary packages
this is how your csporj should look after all package installation

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
      <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <SccProjectName>Svn</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>SubversionScc</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>Svn</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>Svn</SccLocalPath>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>2.3</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
 <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <!--<PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81;</PackageTargetFallback>-->
    <UserSecretsId>99526e66-801d-4816-b800-279edbf6d971</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
   <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
   <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="BCrypt.Net-Core" Version="1.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Design" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Xml.XmlDocument" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.1" />
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>



  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\" />
    <Folder Include="Data\" />
    <Folder Include="Views\Temp\" />
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\css\" />
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\images\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>

    <None Include="Views\Shared\Error.cshtml" />
    <None Include="Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml" />

    <None Include="Views\_ViewImports.cshtml" />
    <None Include="Views\_ViewStart.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```